# SQLite-net TableQuery<T>.Select() poor performance

Tags: c#, performance, linq, sqlite-net

Consider the full code block further below, specifically this part - the object initialization (is that what you'd call it?):

```
new LocalFileInfo() {
  IsFavorite = p.IsFavorite,
  ...
  WhenCrawled = p.WhenCrawled
}
```

Is there anyway to abstract away this code into something such as a method that I can reuse, instead of copy-n-pasting the object initialization code into every query?  My strong preference is for the best performing code rather than the easiest to maintain (but obviously easy to maintain would be desirable).

```
public static List<LocalFileInfo> RecentlyCrawledFiles(int take)
{
    if (take < 1) take = 1;

    List<LocalFileInfo> list = new List<LocalFileInfo>();

        using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), sqliteDb))
        {
            // works but is slower.
            // list = (from p in conn.Table<LocalFileInfo>() select p).OrderBy(f => f.WhenCrawled).Take(take).ToList();

            list = (from p in conn.Table<LocalFileInfo>() select new LocalFileInfo() {
                IsFavorite = p.IsFavorite,
                LastModified = p.LastModified,
                Name = p.Name,
                ParentFolder = p.ParentFolder,
                Path = p.Path,
                Size = p.Size,
                SourceId = p.SourceId,
                SourceName = p.SourceName,
                SourceType = p.SourceType,
                WhenCrawled = p.WhenCrawled
            })
            .OrderByDescending(f => f.WhenCrawled)
            .Take(take)
            .ToList();
        };

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to project your query to the same type?

Comment: Hmmm, might just be a newbie mistake on my part.

Comment: This is who I would do it: `conn.Table<LocalFileInfo>().OrderByDescending(f => f.WhenCrawled)
            .Take(take).ToList();`

Comment: @octavioccl - that looks very similar to the code that's commented out in my OP - it works but is slower than explicitly initializing the objects.  This might be of interest http://www.infoworld.com/article/2934465/microsoft-net/best-practices-in-optimizing-linq-performance.html

Comment: Pretty sure that if you are taking every property, then not explicity initializing the objects will be faster.  Explicitly projecting to objects is only faster if you aren't taking all the properties, that way the source doesn't have to retrieve properties that aren't going to be used, which can also lead to better use of indexes if all the properties you are actually going to use are contained in an index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've taken a look at the source code of the master branch in [SQLite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net)

That library appears to ignore your projections so I don't think having an expression for them will help in any way

See for example in `SqlLite.cs` the `TableQuery<T>` class

```
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator ()
    {
        if (!_deferred)
            return GenerateCommand("*").ExecuteQuery<T>().GetEnumerator();

        return GenerateCommand("*").ExecuteDeferredQuery<T>().GetEnumerator();
    }
```

This `GetEnumerator()` method is used every time you do `ToList()` or `foreach (var item in query)`.

The `GenerateCommand()` will build the SQL, and it "theoretically" supports a string parameter `selectList`, but the library will never use this parameter

Also, when you do a `Select(Expression)` the libary stores a `_selector` private property but will never use it in the call to `GenerateCommand()`, or any other call

**[This issue has been reported](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/322)**

So, I think your best bet regarding performance is this:

```
var list = conn.Table<LocalFileInfo>()
    .OrderByDescending(f => f.WhenCrawled)
    .Take(take)
    .ToList();
```

You can do a `Select<T>()` after this, but the library has already loaded the whole entity list along with every single property. Though, maybe, selecting after the fact can help you with GC if you are keeping those entities around (that is, projection after `ToList()` won't give you any immediate gains).

Or use the `Query<T>()` from the connection object... which will lead you back into the SQL land.

Alternatively, wait for **[Entity Framework Core to support Xamarin](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-entity-framework-core-1-1/)**

There's a mention in the [Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap):

> Xamarin works in some scenarios but has not been fully tested as a supported scenario.

Sorry but that's the best I can come up with for the moment :(

**EDIT:** In fact, I believe that if you do a `Select(p => p.IsFavorite)` the library will fail miserably since it can't map your projection (not bashing the library, just a heads up)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
list = (from p in conn.Table<LocalFileInfo>() select new LocalFileInfo() {
            IsFavorite = p.IsFavorite,
            LastModified = p.LastModified,
            Name = p.Name,
            ParentFolder = p.ParentFolder,
            Path = p.Path,
            Size = p.Size,
            SourceId = p.SourceId,
            SourceName = p.SourceName,
            SourceType = p.SourceType,
            WhenCrawled = p.WhenCrawled
        })
```

how about:

```
list = conn.Table<LocalFileInfo>()
```

That works as long as you are projecting all the properties, and into the same object type.  If either of those aren't true, then you can actually abstract it out like this:

```
public static class FromObjectExtensions
{
  public static IEnumerable<ToObject> ToToObject(this IEnumerable<FromObject> q)
  {
    return q.Select(t=>new ToObject
    {
       Property1=t.Property1,
       ...
    };
  }
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
list = conn.Table<LocalFileInfo>().ToToObject();
```

Just replace `ToObject` and `FromObject` with your actual object types, and fill in the properties to copy.

Comment: This assumes he's projecting every property. If he's only projecting some, then this wouldn't accomplish that.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I was already in the process of writing up how to do it otherwise when you left the comment, but it is a valid point.

Comment: FWIW, yes am am taking every property - for now and the foreseeable future.

Comment: This won't work with the library he's using. SQLite-Net does not expose 'IQueryable<T>' AFAIK

Comment: You are right, it only exposes `IEnumerable<T>`.  That's an odd choice.  I'll fix the answer -- same answer just replacing every `IQueryable<T>` with `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 1):

This would work well.

```
     using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), sqliteDb))
        {
  var list = conn.Table<LocalFileInfo>().OrderByDesending(f=>f.WhenCrawled).Take(take).ToList();
        };
```

Although your query works, your reselecting a selected item which makes no sense, notably:

```
 list = (from p in conn.Table<LocalFileInfo>() select new LocalFileInfo() {
                IsFavorite = p.IsFavorite,
                LastModified = p.LastModified,
                Name = p.Name,
                ParentFolder = p.ParentFolder,
                Path = p.Path,
                Size = p.Size,
                SourceId = p.SourceId,
                SourceName = p.SourceName,
                SourceType = p.SourceType,
                WhenCrawled = p.WhenCrawled
            })
```

Since this is Linq, your first collecting the objects, and recreating a new instance of an already declared object. This makes no sense, and is highly inefficient.

Comment: This assumes he's projecting every property. If he's only projecting some, then this wouldn't accomplish that.

Comment: But then why not filter the existing properties and use those instead of creating a new object alltogether?

Comment: How would you propose to accomplish that?

Comment: Per OP :"FWIW, yes am am taking every property - for now and the foreseeable future". SO this approach would work just fine

Comment: They also stated that they were performing exactly the query that you're suggesting, and that it was slower, so *something* is going on there.

Comment: @maximdumont at your suggestion I'll go back later and look at any unnecessary objects I'm creating.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define an `Expression` for your selector:

```
public static Expression<Func<LocalFileInfo, LocalFileInfo>> MyLocalFileInfoSelector = 
    p => new LocalFileInfo() {
            IsFavorite = p.IsFavorite,
            LastModified = p.LastModified,
            Name = p.Name,
            ParentFolder = p.ParentFolder,
            Path = p.Path,
            Size = p.Size,
            SourceId = p.SourceId,
            SourceName = p.SourceName,
            SourceType = p.SourceType,
            WhenCrawled = p.WhenCrawled
        };
```

You can then use that wherever you want:

```
return conn.Table<LocalFileInfo>()
    .Select(MyLocalFileInfoSelector)
    .OrderBy(f => f.WhenCrawled)
    .Take(take)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: The right approach for EF, LinqToSQL etc. But looks like this specific [ORM](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs) does not support query projection :(

Comment: @IvanStoev Then the solution the OP presented that he was trying to recreate, and that he asserted solved his problem, wouldn't work.  This produces identical code to what that is doing.

Comment: Except that it seem to enter `Enumerable` path which has no `Select` with `Expression<...>`. I'm not trying to be offensive, the ORM is unusual and not sure OP knows what he's doing. I couldn't test, but looks like the idea is to chain as many `TableQuery<T>` custom methods like `Where`, `OrderBy`, `Join` etc. before switching to L2O for projection on materialized result containing all table columns.

Comment: @IvanStoev, I can confirm the code works; can also confirm I might not know what I am doing, but then that's why I posted the question :)

Comment: @AdrianK Sorry mate, it wasn't supposed to be offensive to anyone involved. So you are saying Servy's code is working? Why don't you vote it up then, so I can remove the comments. Take my apologies again.

Comment: No worries @IvanStoev :)  I want to try (test & compare) all the answers before I go much further, but that will take a little time as billable work needs to happen first :(

Comment: @Servy - I'm getting a compile error with this code, but it might be me.  Let me know if I should re-post this as a new question.   (SQLite.Net.)'TableQuery<LocalFileInfo>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Select<LocalFileInfo, LocalFileInfo>(IQueryable<LocalFileInfo>, Expression<Func<LocalFileInfo, LocalFileInfo>>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<LocalFileInfo>'